# Boundary Value Problem using shooting method and Picard's method for successive approximations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem

Hi Guys i am working on the following question

$$y''+2y'=e^{-x}$$
$$y(0)=1,y(1)=4$$

The Question states Obtain a numerical solution to the given boundary value problem when x = 0.25, x =0.5 and x =0.75 by using- one iteration of the shooting method with initial guess
$$m_0 = 4 ,m_1 = 5 $$

along with four iterations of Picard's method, now previous to this question i was asked to work out the the same solution using the finite difference method.

This is what I have attempted thus far

$$z = y'$$
$$z' = y''$$
$$z' = e^{-x}+2z$$

Therefore my two main equations are

$$z = y'$$

$$z' = e^{-x}+2z$$

Therefore by picards method for successive approximations i used the folllowing

$$y_{n+1} = y_0 + \int_0^x Z_n dx$$
and in a similar manner
$$Z_{n+1} = Z_0 + \int_0^x (e^{-x}+ 2z) dx$$

Therefore evaluating y0

$$y_{1} = y_0 + \int_0^x Z_0 dx$$

I know that $Z_0 = y'_0$ but my confusion here is what to substitute into the equation so i substituted it as m for an initial gradient

$$y_{1} = 1 + \int_0^x m dx$$
$$y_1 = 1+mx$$

Now considering the $Z_{n+1}$ this is how i deal with this part of the problem
$$Z_{n+1} = Z_0 + \int_0^x (e^{-x}+ 2z_0) dx$$
$$Z_1 = m + \int_0^x (e^{-x}+ 2m) dx$$
$$Z_1 = 2mx+m+1-e^{-x}$$

Now my thinking is I am required to evaluate 4 iteration so i need to calculate a y2, y3 and y4

$$y_{2} = y_0 + \int_0^x Z_1 dx$$

Now for my $Z_1$ expression that was derived previously therefore i can make a substitution

$$y_2 = y_0 + \int_0^x 2mx + m + 1 -e^{-x}$$

$$y_2 = mx^2+mx+x+e^{-x}+2$$

Now calculating $Z_2$ and im confused as to expression I am integrating to obtain $Z_2$ and this is my expression for obtaining $Z_2$

$$Z_2 = m + \int^x_0 Z_1 dx$$
$$Z_2 = m + \int^x_0 2mx+m+1-e^{-x} dx$$

this will give the following

$$Z_2 = m + mx^2+mx+x+e^{-x}-1$$

Therefore i can obtain an expression for $y_3$ such that

$$y_3 = y_0 + \int^x_0 Z_2 dx$$

Therefore i am currently trying to understand if I am formulating the question properly by trying to obtain the 4 iterations of picards method and then evaluating one iteration of the shooting method. Can anyone clarify or guide to working out this problem. The part of the question is aii)

[image]

Comment: Could you explain in abstract terms, $y'=f(x,y)$, $y(x)=(y_1(x),y_2(x)$, $y_1(a)=y_a$, $y_1(b)=y_b$, how you solve a boundary value problem with the Picard iteration? // Shooting requires here 2 evaluations with initial values $y(a)=(y_a, m_{1,2})$ as the problem is linear, and so is the relation of initial slope and final value. But what are the 4 Picard iterations supposed to achieve?

Comment: well the question is as follows and i know that for the shooting method one is required to evaluate the the different slopes.I added the actual question so you'll understand how it was asked and what was done before @LutzLehmann

Comment: @LutzLehmann i think the picards approximations generates a final term in terms of the variable m which is used as an expression to solve for the different values of x that is required but i am not `100% sure as am i am trying to work out the picards iterations as you can see above.

Comment: So in a.i) you solve the linear system of the equations $$\frac{y_{n+1}-2y_n+y_{n-1}}{h^2}+\frac{y_{n+1}-y_{n-1}}h=e^{-x_n}, ~~n=1,2,3.$$ What numerical method is proposed to be used for the integrals in the Picard iteration in a.ii)? I suppose what I do not understand is that the Picard iteration is a theoretical device to prove things about initial value problems, not a numerical method, and then one more step apart from a numerical method for boundary value problems. You could as well use the Green kernel for the second derivative, at least that is related to boundary value problems.

Comment: Perhaps this "4 iterations of the Picard method" is meant to be "4 steps of the Euler method"? What do your notes and other course materials say about the Picard method as a numerical method?

Comment: @LutzLehmann the picards method is based on using succesive approximations but in terms of the method its different to euler's method

Answer (score 1):

You made a sign error. And the formula for $z_2$ is mixed up with the formula for $y_2$. As the formula for $y_n$ shows, you do not need any previous iterate of $y$, for $y_4$ you only need $z_3$. Then
\begin{align}
z_1(x)&=m+\int_0^x (e^{-s}-2z_0(s))\,ds=m-2mx+(1-e^{-x})\\
z_2(x)&=m+\int_0^x (e^{-s}-2z_1(s))\,ds=m-2mx+2mx^2+(3-2x-3e^{-x})\\
z_3(x)&=m+\int_0^x (e^{-s}-2z_2(s))\,ds=m-2mx+2mx^2+...+(7-7e^{-x}+...)\\
y_4(x)&=y(0)+\int_0^xz_3(s)\,ds=1-mx-mx^2+\frac23x^3+...-7(1-x-e^{-x})+...
\end{align}
However, this is hardly a numerical method, you could as well just integrate, apply the integrating factor and integrate again.

---

I take it that in a.i you apply divided differences to obtain the 3 linear equations
$$
\frac{y_{n+1}-2y_n+y_{n-1}}{h^2}+\frac{y_{n+1}-y_{n-1}}h=e^{-x_n}, ~~n=1,2,3,
$$
for the 3 unknowns $y_1,y_2,y_3$ and solved that system.

Comment: yes i did apply divided differences and solved three linear equations and got values for y for each of the x values required which was simple but this method has me a bit confused for settign up this picard method along with the shooting method @LutzLehman. I see what your saying about my mistake in integrating the terms as well.

Comment: Using the finite difference method i was able to compute an approximation of the values so i know i what are the approximate solutions but for this question its a bit confusing